# Pass Python variable to my C++ script and g++ invocation

Tags: python, c++, gcc, g++

In my Python script I run my C++ script using:

```
os.system('g++ -std=c++0x mutualcepepe.cpp -o mutualout')
```

It works, but I  want to pass my Python changeable (user defines its value) variable to C++ in this command line, for example variable:

```
threshold = 1.33
```

(it can be also a string I can cast it to float in C++ script)

I tried even to pass the exact value:

```
os.system('g++ -std=c++0x mutualcepepe.cpp 1.33 -o mutualout')
```

or:

```
os.system('g++ -std=c++0x mutualcepepe.cpp -o mutualout' 1.33)
```

but I still get the same error:

```
g++: error: 1.33 (or threshold): No such file or directory
```

I searched for solutions on the net, but I didn't find an answer.

I have other idea to put ONLY this value in other text file which I will open and get the value, but still want to to this a little bit more elegantly.

Is there a way to pass that variable which wouldn't be considered by `g++` as a directory?

Comment: Programming by guessing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `-D` option to add a macro:

```
g++ -D "threshold = 1.33" ...
```

then you would refer to the macro value `threshold` in `mutualcepepe.cpp`.

Comment: Okay, but the treshold value will be changable (user define its value), it won't be static

Comment: you don't mean : `os.system('g++ -D "threshold = ' + str(threshold) + '"...')`?

Comment: Much thanks @Sébastien Guarnay , it finally worked! :))